# Dynamically change desktop background from bash script

Tags: linux, desktop

Is it possible to change the GNOME desktop background during some period of time by just a random phrase from the list on black screen? Will is seriously load the CPU and consume battery life?

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by "just a random phrase from the list on black screen"?

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done by using Scalable Vector Graphics in `Inkscape`.  Draw a black box, add a text element with desired color and size, type `REPLACEMENT` into it, save it as `/path/to/template.svg`.

Then, in your script do

```
sed 's/REPLACEMENT/your text/' < /path/to/template.svg > /tmp/background.svg
gconftool-2 --type string --set  /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename /tmp/background.svg
```